# Batch Apex error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void executeBatch(LeadProcessorTest) from the type Database

Tags: apex, batch, class

I'm working on the Use Batch Apex trailhead module and am getting an error on deployment.

> force-app\main\default\classes\LeadProcessorTest.cls  **Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void executeBatch(LeadProcessorTest) from the type Database (16:31)**

What am I missing? I've looked all over and can't find any discrepancy. Help?

LeadProcessor.cls class:

```java
public class LeadProcessor implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.Stateful {
    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator('SELECT ID, LeadSource FROM Lead');
    }

    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Lead> scope){
        //process each batch of records
        List<Lead> leads = new List<Lead>();
        for (Lead lead : scope){
            lead.LeadSource = 'Dreamforce';
            //add lead to the list of leads to be updated
            leads.add(lead);
        }
        update leads;

    }

    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){
        System.debug('Updated all Leads with LeadSource as DREAMFORCE');
    }
}
```

LeadProcessorTest class:

```java
@isTest
private class LeadProcessorTest {
    @testSetup
    static void setup() {
        List<Lead> leads = new List<Lead>();
        //insert 200 leads
        for (Integer i=0;i<200;i++) {
            leads.add(new Lead(LastName='Lead '+i));
        }
        insert leads;
    }

    @isTest static void test(){
        Test.startTest();
        LeadProcessorTest lpt = new LeadProcessorTest();
        Id batchId = Database.executeBatch(lpt);
        Test.stopTest();

        // after the testing stops, assert records were updated properly
        System.assertEquals(200, [select count() from lead where LeadSource = 'Dreamforce']);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your test method erroneously creates and tries to execute a LeadProcessorTest instance instead of a LeadProcessor instance.

Comment: @PhilW BAHAHAH of course it is something as simple as that. I overlooked that for going on 8 hours now. Thank you sir.

Comment: LeadProcessor lpt = new LeadProcessor();

Comment: Seems like Phil has eagle eyes

Comment: Either that or I'm blind as a drunken bat